# How can I check that at particular position there is a element present or not

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I check that at particular position, meaning: particular at an x and y position, that
there is a element present or not.

In jQuery, Javascript

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you may want it, you have these options:

- [position](http://api.jquery.com/position/)
- [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)